# Amazon SNS no envía caracteres como Ñ, ñ

Tags: php, sms

estoy intentando enviar un mensaje a través del SDK de  Amazon SNS para PHP, todo va bien hasta que intento enviar un mensajes con el carácter "Ñ" 0 "ñ", el mensaje llega sin este carácter y según tengo entendido este hace parte del conjunto de caracteres GSM 03.38. ¿Qué puedo estar haciendo mal o me hace falta configurar algo para enviar estos caracteres?

Así estoy publicando los mensajes.

```
$result = $client->publish(array(
        'Message' => $msg,
        'PhoneNumber' => '+57'.$cell_phone,
        'MessageAttributes' => array(
            'AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID' => array(
                'DataType' => 'String', 
                'StringValue' => '123456789'
            ),
            'AWS.SNS.SMS.MaxPrice' => array(
                'DataType' => 'Number', 
                'StringValue' => '0.01'
            ),
            'AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType' => array(
                'DataType' => 'String', 
                'StringValue' => 'Promotional'
            ),
        ),
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Podés probar con la función `utf8_encode()` para que tome los caracteres en el formato UTF-8.
 Si quieres enviar el array completo podés utilizar la función `utf8_encode_deep()`. Acá va el ejemplo:

```
utf8_encode($msg);
$result = $client->publish(array(
        'Message' => $msg,
        'PhoneNumber' => '+57'.$cell_phone,
        'MessageAttributes' => array(
            'AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID' => array(
                'DataType' => 'String', 
                'StringValue' => '123456789'
            ),
            'AWS.SNS.SMS.MaxPrice' => array(
                'DataType' => 'Number', 
                'StringValue' => '0.01'
            ),
            'AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType' => array(
                'DataType' => 'String', 
                'StringValue' => 'Promotional'
            ),
        ),
    ));
```